# Rails 7.0 send_data and pdf file is not displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf

I am newbie in Rails 7.0. I have a web page with buttons with associated different pdf files. When I click on one of these buttons I would open the correspondent pdf file that is stored in my file system in a new web tab. The current behavior is the PDF file is not opened in new tab.

The log files reports...

```
Processing by WelcomeController#openPDF as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "pdf_file"=>"/mnt/c/Users/sfolco/Desktop/da chiavetta/devel/rubydevel/bin/ArchivematicaTools/testOMNES/5/016801_fcn.pdf"}
File to open is /mnt/c/Users/sfolco/Desktop/da chiavetta/devel/rubydevel/bin/ArchivematicaTools/testOMNES/5/016801_fcn.pdf
  Rendering text template
  Rendered text template (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 4)
Sent data 1.pdf (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 0.3ms | Allocations: 473)
```

If I move the openPDF code in index action, the PDF is opend in the web page.

This is my code

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    .....
  end
  def load
    ..... 
  end
  def openPDF

    data = open(params[:pdf_file],'rb').read
    send_data(data, type: 'application/pdf', filename: "1.pdf", disposition: 'inline')

  end
```

end

load.erb file is

```
<%=button_to 'Open', welcome_openPDF_path(pdf_file: file), method: :post %>
<li><%=file%></li>
```

while the routes.rb is:

```
  get 'welcome/index'

  root 'welcome#index'

  post 'welcome/load'
  post 'welcome/openPDF'
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `target: _blank` as a form attribute to [`button_to`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) to open the PDF in a new page, so your code becomes:

```
<%= button_to 'Open', welcome_openPDF_path(pdf_file: file), method: :post, form: { target: '_blank' } %>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this solution doesn't work. The PDF is not opend in new tab. Log file: The log file reports the same previous messages.

Comment: could you tell me the name of the browser you're testing it on?

Comment: Chrome 114.0.5735.134

Comment: Okay, I found the issue, it's NOT related to your browser at all my bad, it's rather related to `button_to` block. Could you update the `button_to` block as follows, it should solve your problem:


`<%= button_to welcome_openPDF_path(pdf_file: file), method: :post, form: { target: '_blank' } do %>
        Open
      <% end %>`

Comment: Not working. If I change the <%= link_to file, welcome_downloadPDF_path(pdf_file: file),target: '_blank'  %>   I am able to download or open in new tab the pdf file.

Comment: Did you update the route from `POST` to `GET`? The code I shared with `button_to` will work too without the `method: :post` part in that case. Please don't forget to upvote if it solved your original issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `data-turbo: false` as a attribute to button_to

```rb
<%= button_to 'Open', welcome_openPDF_path(pdf_file: file), method: :post, data: { turbo: false } %>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).